# FOSUserBundle - overriding templates

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've just installed `FOSUserBundle` and I'm trying to override the templates to use my own custom layout.

I have a bundle, `BMCmsBundle`, that has a layout.html.twig file in

`src/BM/CmsBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig`

Looking through the docs, I have created the following file:

`app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig`

How do I then use my own template, i.e. CSS/jS?
I've tried in the FOS layout.html.twig file to use the following:

`{% extends 'BMCmsBundle::layout.html.twig' %}`

But once again, this doesn't seem to work, any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After creating your new layout at

```
app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig
```

Make sure you also clear your cache:

```
 php app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the opposite.

Your layout in BMCmsBundle has to extend the one in app/Resources with the command :

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}
```